# Where put a subquery in a oracle outer query

Tags: oracle, subquery

Is it possible to put a subquery in a group by clause of the outer query?

Example:

```
select (select max(salary) from employees)  from employees
group by (select max(salary) from employees);
```

I know that it is possible with the clauses below:

- select
- from
- where
- having

Comment: what you are trying to achieve here? can you please give information of sample input and expected output?

Comment: i have read two books giving differents versions about the place where can be put a subquery.

Comment: The query makes no sense. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot put a subquery in a group by clause. If you want to achieve it, then use subquery in `select` clause, give it an alias, and use this as a subquery. Then in outer query, you can use the alias in group by.
So your query can be changed like this.

**Note: This query is just for your understanding purpose on how to achieve what you are asking. The output of this can be achieved in numerous better ways as well.**

```
select max_sal from
(select (select max(salary) from employees) as max_sal 
from employees)
group by max_sal;
```

Try to implement it in your scenario and let us know in case of any issues.

Comment: Then what are you asking. Please elaborate and edit the question.

Comment: **I know rules about grouping functions and use of the group by clause** and i tried this query:
 `select last_name, employee_id,(select avg(salary) from employees )
from employees
group by  last_name, employee_id,(select avg(salary) from employees )`
my goal is to know which book i a read say true about putting subquery in a group by clause 
@BhaveshGhodasara